# Using an If statement to find prime numbers

Tags: c, if-statement, primality-test

The following is a piece of code that shows an output stating whether a number, entered by a user, is a prime number or not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int a,b;
int main(void) {

 printf("Enter number: ");
 fflush(stdout);
 scanf("%d",&a);

 for (b = 2; b < a; b++)
 {
   if (a % b == 0)
    break;
 }

 if (b<a)
 {
   printf ("%d is divisible by %d\n", a, b);
 }

 else
 {
   printf ("%d is prime \n", a);
 }
return 0;
}
```

The piece of code, written above, is not mine and it identifies a prime number successfully everytime (i.e the **printf** statement of the **else** clause gets printed).

My understanding of the **if** statement is that an **else** clause in an **if-else** statement belongs to the nearest **if** statement which doesn't already have an **else** clause. And so, having said that, I believe the **else** clause, in the above piece of code, belongs to the nearest **if** statement.

My question is this: If the user enters a prime number like 31 or 37 or any other prime number, how does the **printf** statement of the **else** clause get printed?
The condition `if (b<a)` (of the second **if** statement) will always be true considering that b will only be incremented to `(a-1)`. And so if the user enters the number 31, the variable **b** will only be incremented to 30. Shouldn't it be the case that the **printf** statement of the second **if** statement gets printed, regardless of whether the number entered by the user is prime or not, considering that the condition `if (b<a)` will always be true?

How does the above piece of code print all the prime numbers correctly, and therefore, work alright? (when, according to my limited understanding of the way the **if** statement works, it shouldn't)

Comment: You are missing the fact that there is a conditional `break` in the `for` loop. Which means it can exit early without going through all the iterations of the `for` loop.

Comment: @Rabbid76 - You mean `for (b = 2; b < floor(sqrt(a)); b++)` :-)

Comment: Thank you for the answers, everyone.

Comment: @AndrewCheong wouldn't it be `ceil(sqrt(a))` ?  else it tells that 49 is prime.

Answer (score 4):

> The condition `if (b<a)` (of the second if statement) will always be true considering that b will only be incremented to `(a-1)`.

That is not the case. If no divisor is found, the for loop continues until the condition `b<a` is false. This happens when `b == a`, not `b == a-1`. The loop body isn't run when the loop condition is false, but the increment has happened nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

This loop

```
for (b = 2; b < a; b++)
{
  if (a % b == 0)
   break;
}
```

can be interrupted in two cases. The first one is when `a` is divisible by `b`

```
  if (a % b == 0)
   break;
```

But for prime numbers this condition is always will be equal to false.

So the other case when the loop will be interrupted is when `b` after increment

```
for (b = 2; b < a; b++)
                   ^^^
```

will became equal to `a`. In this case the condition

```
for (b = 2; b < a; b++)
            ^^^^^
```

will be equal to false and the control will be passed to the if-else statement.
If so then `b` is equal to `a` and `a` is a prime number.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are correct, the whitespace between

```
if (b<a)
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
else
{
    ...
}
```

doesn't matter. The `else` indeed belongs to the `if`.

Second, it's not true that the `if (b<a)` is always true. As long as `a % b == 0` never returned true, the loop continues until `b==a`, which fails the condition. They could have also written `if (b!=a)`.

Comment: `if (b<a)` has the advantage over  `if (b!=a)` should the value of `a` entered is `<= 1`.